# Как отредактировать реестр в Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Как отредактировать реестр в Windows Phone 8? Возможно ли это вообще и с какими заморочками можно столкнуться?

Comment: Не уверен, что что-либо вне сэндбокса (реестр, настоящая файловая система, других процессы) будет доступно на WP8. Приложение как бы изолировано от системы, чтобы не напортить системе (и другим приложениям).

Comment: Да уж, перерыл половину 4pda, на данный момент возможно только на samsung и то с бубном и анлоком. Будем ждать пока реверсеры не поработают.
p.s. WP7 сломали, и отлом 8 не за горами.
p.p.s. есть заготовка на плюсах: https://wp8nativeaccess.codeplex.com/
но она дает доступ только на чтение.

Comment: @z668: А зачем вам ломать сэндбокс? На Аппстор (или как там оно называется у Microsoft) с такой программой явно не пустят. Или вы в хакерских целях?

Comment: @VladD: у меня Nokia 520, и когда я увидел внезапно появившийся алфавит (не очень удобный и явно некрасивый кстати), я потратил минут 10 на ковыряние настроек, потом минут 20 на поиск по интернету. Так что программа в первую очередь для себя, если в аппстор не удастся загнать - всегда есть форумы. Но тут уже ждать реверсеров.

Comment: @z668: Если вы пишете для себя хакерскую приблуду, не стоит надеяться, что вам дадут хороший API для этого. Легче всего наверное написать полностью нативное приложение командной строки, зачем вам UI?

Comment: @VladD: да не хаккерская она, простое изменение того что не догадались включить разработчики. Если не свободные разработчики - то кто напишет то - что нужно пользователю? =)

Comment: Для WP7 был проект джейлбрейка с возможностью выхода из песочницы и доступа к фс и реестру.

Comment: @Олег Нечитайло: на 7 видел, да там помоему он не один, пока искал на 8 встретил несколько редакторов реестра, один из них был даже интегрирован в настройки.